# second deritive test why works

Tags: calculus

If I know first derivative at a point  is 0 for function parabola, and first derivative for function cubic at apoint is 0 but one is a min and one is a inflection point. Why is it that even though both functions share this fact one is inflection but one is min?

Answer (score 3):

If the first derivative is zero, then it only means that the tangent to the graph at that point is a horizontal line. You don't know what's happening at the points on the left and right side. Maybe they're increasing, maybe not.

The second derivative test at a point where the first derivative is zero tells us if the *first* derivative is increasing, i.e. first derivative is going from being negative to postive, or whether it's decreasing, i.e. going from being positive to negative. If the first derivative is going from being negative to positive (second derivative is positive) then the actual graph initially is decreasing then there's a stationary point (horizontal tangent) then it is increasing. In other words, it's a minimum. The other case is similar for a negative second derivative.

**I urge you to draw this out and you'll find it much more convincing.**

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be a curve

1. $f'(x)$ tells you the slope of the $f(x)$, when this is positive $f(x)$ is going up, when negative $f(x)$ is going down and when zero $f(x)$ is flat.
2. $f''(x)$ tells you the slope of $f'(x)$, when this is positive $f'(x)$ is going up (a minimum in $f(x)$), when negative $f'(x)$ is going down (a maximum in $f(x)$) and when zero $f'(x)$ is flat (an inflection in $f(x)$).

You can think of this physically if you think of $f(x)$ as measuring the distance of an object (in 1-dimension) from the origin.above the ground. In this case $f'(x)$ measures velocity and $f''(x)$ measures acceleration.

When $f(x)>0$, the object is above the ground, when $f(x)<0$ it is below the ground and when $f(x)=0 it is on the ground.

When $f'(x)>0$, the object is moving up, when $f'(x)<0$ it is moving down and when $f'(x)=0 it is stopped.

When $f''(x)>0$, the object is accelerating up (going faster if it is moving up or slowing down if it is moving down, when $f''(x)<0$ it is accelerating down (vice-versa) and when $f''(x)=0 it moving at a constant velocity.